# react native picker packaging components

Tags: react-native

child component

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
  <Picker
      selectedValue={this.props.questions}
      onValueChange={}//I do not know how to write here
      // onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({questions1 :value})}
      mode="dropdown"
      style={{color:'#f00'}}
      >
      <Picker.Item label="1" value="1"/>
      <Picker.Item label="2" value="2"/>
      <Picker.Item label="3" value="3"/>
      <Picker.Item label="4" value="4"/>
    </Picker>
  </View>
```

parent component

```
render() {
    var items=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      this.state["questions"+i]=1
      items.push(
        <SelectValue            
        questions={this.state['questions'+i]}>
        </SelectValue>
      )
    }
    return (        
          {items}
    )
```

Now I don't know how to write the onValueChange={}.
I want the child component(picker) can be reused.
So when the picker's value change the parent state also change, that what I want

Answer (score 0):

from parent component you can pass a function as a prop.

```
    render() {
      var items=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
       this.state["questions"+i]=1
       items.push(
        <SelectValue            
           onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({["questions"+i]:value})}
           questions={this.state['questions'+i]}>
        </SelectValue>
      )
     }
     return ({items})
  }
```

in child component

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <Picker
      selectedValue={this.props.questions}
      onValueChange={this.props.onValueChange}
      mode="dropdown"
      style={{color:'#f00'}}
      >
      <Picker.Item label="1" value="1"/>
      <Picker.Item label="2" value="2"/>
      <Picker.Item label="3" value="3"/>
      <Picker.Item label="4" value="4"/>
    </Picker>
  </View>
```

Comment: But the parent component.
onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({questions1:value})}
there is question1:value, I want it questions i

Comment: When I select one choice, the state. questioni didn't change to the new value. So it didn't work

Comment: I think it didn't change the parent state.questioni